# Menu duplo com jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Gostaria de saber como eu faço um menu igual ao deste site => http://ghfly.com/, de preferencia utilizando somente jQuery e css VLWS!

Comment: Por favor, dê mais detalhes sobre o que quer fazer, dependendo, eu tenho alguns exemplos funcionais que fiz em alguns sites, ou até mesmo poderia aprofundar um pouco mais, para que você pudesse desenvolver algo até melhor do que você planeja :D

Comment: Se possível também, disponibilize o que você já conseguiu realizar até agora

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer esse efeito do "segundo menu", você pode alterar o CSS quando a posição da página for maior que **x**.

Com esse jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    x = 100;

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > x){

        // Aparece com efeito de meio segundo e fixa no topo da pagina
        $('#cabecalho').slideDown(500).css({'position':'fixed'});
    } 
});
```

Comment: complicou dms uma coisa que é fácil de fazer :/
mas o efeito do slide down é realmente preciso :)

Comment: Por que diz isso? são apenas 5 linhas... O resto não é necessário?

Comment: declaração de variável `x = 100` desnecessária, isso já é, mesmo que insignificante uma coisa desnecessária, imagina se voc fizer um código grande e encher de declarações desnecessárias, isso já da um peso a mais, tudo bem, apenas uma linha, mas é bom evitar sempre :)

Comment: Foi apenas para demonstrar que ali pode ser qualquer valor, mas valeu pelo comentário :)

Comment: entendo :D então foi uma boa demonstração